# OleDB Read Excel decimal value

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, decimal, culture

I am using OleDB Ace 12 to read an Excel (xslx) sheet containing a column with decimal values. When I open the Excel sheet on my PC a decimal value is correctly formatted as `1.850,50` (NLD culture with comma as decimal separator)

When I'm reading out the Excel sheet using OleDB (C#4.0), the string value of this field is always `1,850.50` (US format)

I've tried setting the Locale of the DataSet I fill, set the currentthread's culture and more, but the DataSet filled with OleDB adapter always returns US formatted decimals.

Can I change the way it formats the value when reading? Or is it always US format no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get it US format only. You can convert it in code:

```
string strFloatingNumber = "24.45"; //a floating point number in English notation
double output = 0.0; //output double number which will hold the value
double.TryParse(strFloatingNumber, out output); //convert without exception - assuming no error
MessageBox.Show(output.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL")));
```

Comment: Yes, but test is not 15,11. It would be 15.11 which will throw an exception when using de-DE culture to parse.

Comment: I guess you did not get the hint :) Updated my answer.

Comment: But '1,850.50' won't work. I could replace the comma, you think it's the only solution? I was hoping I could read with a specific culture, but unfortunately it seems not possible. Thanks for your help. (BTW I need Decimal, not Double)

Comment: Try to analyze my answer bit more. You have the answer right here. Study bit more documentation on MSDN - that might help you in understanding how to use this answer.